# How to use group by in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to values in comma seperated.So how to use group/concat in aggregate framework?

Document **contact**

```
{
  "_id" : "9c612c95054fb46e3de8dee8",
  "name" : "name1",
  "oppID" : [
        "5c612c95054fb46e3de8bcc5",
        "5bd6b334cba7d2241a3ba9d9"
       ]
},
{
  "_id" : "1c612c95054fb46e3de8dcde9",
  "name" : "name2",
  "oppID" : [
        "5c612c95054fb46e3de8bcc5",
        "5bd6b334cba7d2241a3ba9d9"
       ]
}
```

Document **opportunity**

```
{
  "_id" : "5c612c95054fb46e3de8bcc5",
  "name" : "opp name 01",
},
{
  "_id" : "5bd6b334cba7d2241a3ba9d9",
  "name" : "opp name 02",
},
```

I want to get contact list like below,

```
{
   "_id" : "9c612c95054fb46e3de8dee8",
   "oppName" : "opp name 01, opp name 02"
},
{
   "_id" : "1c612c95054fb46e3de8dcde9",
   "oppName" : "opp name 01, opp name 02"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to get the data from both collections and then [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html) to transform an array into single string

```
db.contact.aggregate([        
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "opportunity",
            localField: "oppID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "opportunities"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            oppName: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$opportunities",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                        $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$value", "" ] }, "$$this.name", { $concat: [ "$$value", ", ", "$$this.name" ] } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: @ManojGhediya just remove the `$match` then, modified my answer

Comment: When i add $group then after its works. {
                $group: {
                  _id: "$_id",
                  "opportunityArr": { $push: "$opportunity" }
                }
            },  ......... Thank you so much.